# Ruby On rails :param not found: Friends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new for ROR. I am saving data however its show param not found: Friends.

My function is this

```
def follow
  @friend = @model= Friend.new(friend_params)
  @record = @friend.create(:follower_id=>'2',:following_id=>'3')    
end 

def friend_params
  params.require(:Friends).permit(:follower_id, :following_id )
end
```

Comment: Post definition of `friend_params`.

Comment: def friend_params params.require(:Friends).permit(:follower_id, :following_id ) end

Comment: What does the form look like? and why is `:Friends` capitalized? If this is typical Rails the param is coming in as `:friends`.

Comment: Please post the full error.

Answer (score 1):

Edit this method

```
def friend_params 
  params.require(:friend).permit(:follower_id, :following_id) 
end
```

Comment: Then might be the parameters are not coming to the follow action

Comment: What do you have in the form that POSTs to this action?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not posted properly .how and what data you are sending through views is not clear .

If you are new in rails i will suggest you to read the below mention tutorial for this type of application.

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/